# Finding the average when values are missing using SQL

Tags: sql

I'm using Presto but any flavor of SQL will do.

I have a table in that format.

| Group_id | event_id | month | party | time_interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Jan | Player A | 1 hour |
| 1 | 1 | Jan | Player A | 2 hours |
| 1 | 1 | Jan | Player B | 1 hours |
| 1 | 1 | Jan | Player B | 1 hour |
| 1 | 2 | Jan | Player A | 3 hour |

I need to get the average per group_id, per month, per party

Here's how my average should be calculated

`total number of hours per group, per month, per party/total number of events per org, per month`

Here's the output I should be expecting for clarity's sake:

| Group_id | month | party | avg_time_interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | Player A | 3 hours |
| 1 | Jan | Player B | 1 hour |

Now here's the tricky part. For the first row everything makes perfect sense. We have 6 hours across both events, which we divide by 2 distinct events and get an average of 3.

**However for the 2nd row, we get 1 hour instead of 2 because since the user did not get a time included we should be assuming that the interval there was 0**. This means that there are still 2 unique events across that org_id, month. So the 2 hours totaled should be divided by 2 and not by 1.

This missing data essentially has made this way more complicated than it should be. Otherwise I believe running the following would've solved it

```
 SELECT Group_id , month, party, total/num_cases FROM(
 SELECT Group_id , month, party, SUM(time_interval) AS total, COUNT(DISTINCT(event_id)) AS num_cases
 FROM table
 GROUP BY Group_id , month, party
 )
```

Comment: why would player B event 1 count as 2 and player A event 1 count as 1? how are we supposed to know that?

Comment: I don't understand. they all count the same amount. its just that when a user is missing from an event we should be counting his time as 0, thus lowering the average

Comment: Why not just divide by number of events then?

Comment: @DannySlor because they each have a different number of events with the group by, Player A has 2, Player B has 1. Ideally I'd have both of them divided by 2.

I'm doing all of this on AWS's Athena

Comment: I posted an answer with sql server and tried not to use anything complicated. let me know if this is what you're looking for and if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the count of distinct event_id values grouped by group_id, month; then join this with your table as the following:

```
SELECT T.Group_id, T.month, T.party
       ,SUM(T.time_interval)*1.0/ MAX(D.eid) AS avg_time_interval 
FROM tbl T
JOIN 
  (
    SELECT Group_id, month,
           COUNT(DISTINCT event_id) AS eid
    FROM tbl GROUP BY Group_id, month
  ) D
ON T.Group_id=D.Group_id AND
   T.month=D.month
GROUP BY T.Group_id,T.month,T.party
ORDER BY T.Group_id,T.month,T.party
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select    distinct Group_id
         ,month
         ,party
         ,total_hours_per_party/max(dns_rnk) over() as avg_time_interval
from     (
         select   Group_id
                 ,month
                 ,party
                 ,sum(time_interval) over(partition by party) as total_hours_per_party
                 ,dense_rank() over(order by event_id)        as dns_rnk
         from     t
         ) t
```

| Group_id | month | party | avg_time_interval |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan | Player A | 3 |
| 1 | Jan | Player B | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/R93OE6eT)